# Interpretation of “This to be love…” in Hodgson’s ‘The Night Land’

Tags: tenses, conjugation

*The Night Land* by William Hope Hodgson, published in 1912, begins with the lines:

*This to be Love, that your spirit to live in a natural holiness with the Beloved, and your bodies to be a sweet and natural delight that shall be never lost of a lovely mystery…*

> What does he mean by “This to be Love”?

Whatever Hodgson’s exposition, my Question is about the linguistic form “This to be (love or whatever)…”

If it’s meant to be a variant of “This is what love is…” can anyone provide support for that interpretation?

I’m aware that some readers see a slightly different version as important both for its own sake and for the idea that it introduces a pattern of some sort… and anything along those lines is unlikely to be on topic, let alone helpful.

I could follow *… that your spirit lived/s/should live* but that’s not what Hodgson wrote and it's also not the point.

Was the passage exaggerated poetry? Was Hodgson extremely idiosyncratic? Perhaps, but I very much doubt this.

Is there a simple grammatical form that I’m missing?

Comment: Poetry doesn't follow grammatical rules except when the poet wants to. Naturally that makes them mysterious. Enjoy.

Comment: I removed the tag idiosyncracy because there was a typo and yours is the only question. HYDM

Comment: @Mari-Lou A Not at all… Is it only me who can still see that tag "idiosyncracy"? Either way I don't recall creating it and I hope I'd never have wanted to assign it.

Comment: Someone, so it had to be you, created the tag. And, yes, I can still see the tag because you rolled back the edit. Yours is the only question with that tag https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/idiosyncracy The typo refers to the tag name, which is why it caught my eye in the first place. It should have an "s" in place of the "c".

Comment: @Mari-LouA Logically, of course you're right. At the same time, I certainly did not roll back your Edit… I don't know how to!

While very clearly someone created that tag, nothing suggests it "had to be" me.

Comment: Extensive exchanges with the PO over my now deleted answer have persuaded me that this is a matter of irreconcilable opinions. I have therefore voted to close.

Comment: @Anton On the one hand, why not stick at deleting your Answer? Could that hurt?

On the other hand, why not accept that you missed it?

On the gripping hand, who on Earth are you to dare suggesting closure? 

That you fail to grasp the Question is one thing, obvious from the Posts before this. That you take that as any faint suggestion closure might be appropriate is simply outrageous.

Comment: Re. Tags, edits and rollbacks: First you posted your Q, soon after I edited the tags, then Edwin edited the body. After his edit, you rolled back the two edits to the first, untouched, version. It's all recorded in the history stamp https://english.stackexchange.com/revisions/582277/4

Comment: Can we be really clear, I wholly welcome everything Mari-lou A has Posted. At the same time, I have no faint idea how the assurnine "idiosyncracy" tag got here. Who sees some conflict, please explain what that is. Otherwise, can we please just be really clear, I wholly welcome everything Mari-lou A Posted.

Comment: Well thanks and who failed to see that however strongly "opinion based" any or all Answers or Comments might be, the Question was not? Closing a Question for a genuine reason, clearly explained, might be justifiable. How could that apply here? Whoever did it, can you hold your hand up, or must you hide in anonymity? Was it you, Anton?

Comment: Wow, seems I stumbled onto a question with a history. But, "Was the passage exaggerated poesy? Was Hodgson idiosyncratic beyond normal use?" Yes. It's intuitively intelligible but was never a standard construction. Working on a longer answer...

Comment: @AndyBonner Thanks and that seems wholly reasonable. Please drop below my Answer of today… all else has gone by the board.

Comment: I read it as a fusion of 'This is what love truly is:' {explanatory}  and 'This is how we must properly regard love:' {more didactic, hortative}.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks for that, which is clearly true. Sadly, I expressed the OQ so badly, many here missed 'my Question is about the linguistic form “This to be (love or whatever)…” ' which I hoped was asking about the grammatical form, not the semantic meaning.

Thus far, my vote is going to AndyBonner's 'It's intuitively intelligible but was never a standard construction…'

Answer (score 1):

> Was the passage exaggerated poesy? Was Hodgson idiosyncratic beyond normal use?

Yes. It's intuitively intelligible but was never a standard construction.

The quoted passage appears as a sort of preface to the "story proper" ([in this edition](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Night_Land/mcUNCgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22This+to+be+Love,+that+your+spirit+to+live+in+a+natural+holiness+with+the+Beloved%22&pg=PP9&printsec=frontcover) actually headed "Preface"; [in others](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Night_Land/Prologue), presumably more original, with a title "The Dreams That Are Only Dreams"). Notably, it uses quote marks and ellipses as if it's quoting another source:

> “This to be Love, that your spirit to live in a natural holiness with the Beloved, and your bodies to be a sweet and natural delight that shall be never lost of a lovely mystery…. And shame to be unborn, and all things to go wholesome and proper, out of an utter greatness of understanding; and the Man to be an Hero and a Child before the Woman; and the Woman to be an Holy Light of the Spirit and an Utter Companion and in the same time a glad Possession unto the Man…. And this doth be Human Love….”
> “…for this to be the especial glory of Love, that it doth make unto all Sweetness and Greatness, and doth be a fire burning all Littleness; so that did all in this world to have met The Beloved, then did Wantonness be dead, and there to grow Gladness and Charity, dancing in the years.”

It's *possible* that Hodgson is actually quoting another work. If so, I can find no evidence of it, and I think it is much more likely that he has constructed this passage "as if" he were quoting from some pre-existing work. The tone and style are—elevated, to say the least; he uses various archaic touches like "doth," "an holy light," and free capitalization, but he also uses odd constructions with no historical parallel. This seems less about making a convincing forgery of historical styles and more about creating an intentionally oblique, gnomic, "mystic" style as if from forgotten times and realms, or perhaps translated from another language. I haven't read the book, but the gesture seems to be akin to Lovecraft's murky world-building.

One highlight of this invented style is a predilection for the infinitive; the word "to" appears 10 times in the passage. "To be" is used gratuitously, not just in the first sentence, and "doth be" is frequently used where "is" might be expected: "...for this **to be** the especial glory of Love, that it ... **doth be** a fire burning all Littleness..." Both of these can effectively be replaced with "is." So the opening phrase of the quote, "This to be Love," is simply a rendering of "**This is Love**," in a highly stylized and apparently invented tone.

(Of course, if it turns out it's a genuine quote from another work, then we would be tasked with explaining the usages as actual intent to convey meaning.)

Comment: Thanks, Andy. I learned earlier that as you infer, Hodgson was indeed quoting… almost abridging another work.

Sadly, he who explained that went on to Close earlier versions, wholly maiming the topic, rather than permit me to doubt his well-meant ideas were conclusive.… which also deleted the quotes and links showing where it first came from.

The drug-cops taught me the problem is that transposed, "You are…" works because it's second person, while "You to be…" never will because it attempts to twist second and third persons into one.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, some cops and drug dealers in a TV docco explained why that phrase seemed odd.

'We believe you are deeply involved in bad stuff,' the cops said.

'We believe you to be deeply involved in bad stuff,' I thought.

'We believe this to be the reason you're involved in bad stuff,' seems to me to follow from that.

That I myself can't describe it is clearly my own problem, yet can anyone else?

Answer (score 0):

> This to be Love

You would understand it as

"This is what the circumstances are/must be for it to be love."

In the above "This" is cataphoric pointing to the conditions/definition that follows.

Comment: Thanks Greybeard and I don't think that's the point. On the one hand, of course it means "This is what the circumstances are/must be for it to be love" but that's semantic. I thought I was asking about grammar, and I still think the drug cops showed the way.

Comment: I think the title *"How else might we have expressed..."* misled me. You speak of addressing the grammar, but I see no grammar referenced in the "drug cops." Can you help?

Comment: Sorry. This is the second major revision of what started out as a simple Question: What part of speech was "This to be love" about which I had Asked whether I was missing a tense or conjugation, declension or something else; no-one knew.

Earlier versions were Closed by a contributor who deemed it better to kill the topic than allow me to doubt his well-meant ideas were conclusive.

The drug-cops dialogue showed that the phrase seems odd because it's wrong, as evidenced by transposing "you to be…"

Does that make sense? I'll happily expound, at risk of being Closed again

Comment: The question is not simple: "This to be love" is not a part of speech, i.e. noun, verb, adv. adj, etc: it is a construction of some sort.  I have looked again at the "cops and drug dealers" and see no connection with "This to be love".

Comment: I apologise for trying to use "part of speech" for “kind/type of grammar/semantics/vocabulary/whatever…" What should I have said?

In "cops and drug dealers" how could you not see "This to be…"? 

"We believe you are deeply involved in bad stuff," the cops said.

"We believe you to be deeply involved in bad stuff," I thought. How are they not equivalent?

If you drop “We believe…” - which is all I’m Asking about - what remains?

Could “You are…” mean anything by itself?

Could “You to be…” mean anything by itself?

Comment: Not my take. I'd say it's a variant on 'This is what real love is ...', with the part-irrealis thrown in to show that the words or perhaps the best human efforts (not the actuality) can't don't do justice to ultimate truth.